# How to convert float to int in a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I am facing problem in converting float to int in python list.

One of the elements of the list looks like this:

```
{'artForm': 'Madur',
  'artistName': 'Bharati Dolai',
  'gender': 'F',
  'district': 'Paschim Medinipur',
  'phone': '',
  'artisanCard': {'exists': 'N', 'cardNo': ''},
  'dob': '',
  'age': 45.0,
  'year': 1971.0,
  'education': 'I',
  'childrenGoToSchool': 'Y'
}
```

I am unable to convert the `age` and `year` to int.

My code:

```
for i in range(len(d)):
    int(d[i]['age'])
```

And I get the following error

```
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Desired output:

```
 {'artForm': 'Madur',
      'artistName': 'Bharati Dolai',
      'gender': 'F',
      'district': 'Paschim Medinipur',
      'phone': '',
      'artisanCard': {'exists': 'N', 'cardNo': ''},
      'dob': '',
      'age': 45,                  #converted to int
      'year': 1971,               #converted to int
      'education': 'I',
      'childrenGoToSchool': 'Y'
    }
```

Comment: you have some values that are NaN

Comment: Python doesn't use Typed variables, the closest you could do is int(var) which will cast the variable as an int, however NaN can't be cast, you can check for NaN and or use something like the math library's math.isnan(var)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your values are `NaN`. Also, you missed the assignment operation.

```
import math
for i in range(len(d)):
    if not math.isnan(d[i]['age']):
        d[i]['age'] = int(d[i]['age'])
```

Comment: `if d[i]['age'] is not NaN:` will not work., not only is there no variable `NaN`, you have to use `float('NaN')`, but you shouldn't use `is`

Comment: it has to be `None`

Comment: **no**. You have to use `float("NaN")` and `import math; math.isnan` to check for `NaN`

Answer (score 1):

You have some ages which are `NaNs` in your list. If these cannot be removed you could try wrapping your code in a `try-except` statement:

```
num_of_nans = 0

for entry in d:
    try:
        entry['age'] = int(entry['age'])
    except ValueError:
        entry['age'] = 'Age not known'
        num_of_nans += 1
```

You may want to count the number of NaNs so you have an idea of how many of your entries are missing.

Comment: liked the idea of `ValueError`

Answer (score 1):

Using `dict comprehension`:

```
import math  

print({k: int(v) if k == 'age' or k == 'year' and not math.isnan(v) else v for k,v in d.items()})
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{

 'artForm': 'Madur', 'artistName': 'Bharati Dolai', 'gender': 'F', 
 'district': 'Paschim Medinipur', 'phone': '', 
 'artisanCard': {'exists': 'N', 'cardNo': ''}, 
 'dob': '', 'age': 45, 'year': 1971, 
 'education': 'I', 'childrenGoToSchool': 'Y'

}
```

**EDIT**:

If you only want the specific columns:

```
print({k: int(v) for k, v in d.items() if k == 'age' or k == 'year' and not math.isnan(v)})
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{'age': 45, 'year': 1971}
```

Comment: still getting the same `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer` when age is `NaN`. Adding `and not math.isnan(v)` might help.

Comment: I like the use of dictionary comprehension, but I feel the use of a try-except statement is better, since you need to iterate over the list of dictionaries anyway. Isn't it also inefficient to iterate over the whole dict when you only need to access the `age` key? It feels a bit like doing dict comprehension for the sake of it rather than for the need of it.

Comment: Dirty it you didn’t read the whole question. OP had a list of dicts.

Comment: @FChm I haven't got my caffeine yet ha, two sides of a coin. I'd opt for a dict-comprehension.

Comment: I don't get why you would iterate over all other entries, are dict comprehensions fast enough that its not an issue? (I'm not that familiar with them)

Answer (score 1):

one liner

```
>>> test_dict = {"value1": 111.2, "value2": "asd", "value3": 13.232}
>>> test_dict = {key: int(math.floor(value)) if isinstance(value, float) else value for key, value in test_dict.items()}
>>> test_dict
{'value1': 111, 'value2': 'asd', 'value3': 13}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the same within a `try` block as some of the values for the `'age'` key is `NaN` :

```
for i in range(len(d)):
    try:
        d[i]['age'] = int(d[i]['age'])
    except Exception as e1:
        pass
```

This will also help to avoid those cases where `'age'` key has vacant string like `''`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
d = {'artForm': 'Madur',
  'artistName': 'Bharati Dolai',
  'gender': 'F',
  'district': 'Paschim Medinipur',
  'phone': '',
  'artisanCard': {'exists': 'N', 'cardNo': ''},
  'dob': '',
  'age': 45.0,
  'year': 1971.0,
  'education': 'I',
  'childrenGoToSchool': 'Y'
}


for i in range(len(d)):
    #convert age to int and replace age
    d['age'] = int(d['age'])
#if you want to convert all the floats to ints:
for k in list(d):#list d to get all the key
    #test is float?
    if isinstance(d[k], float):
        #yes? convert it to int
        d[k] = int(d[k])
    #else pass
    else:
        pass

print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to have a default value if the property is missing or incorrect. and you don't need to use range to loop a list.

```py
for u in d:
    try:
        u["age"] = int(u["age"])
    except ValueError:
        u["age"] = 0

    try:
        u["year"] = int(u["year"])
    except ValueError:
        u["year"] = 0
```